# Downloading excel file from MS teams into Azure Data Lake using ADF/ADB/PowerShell

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-powershell, azure-data-lake-gen2

We would like to read file thats available in MS Teams Files folder (Connected to Sharepoint) into ADLS using ADF/ADB/Powershell. While trying HTTP connector from ADF, connection is initially successful with individual credentials but retrieving the sheets failed with "Access forbidden" error. Please suggest if there is access needs to be shared to Azure for MS Teams and how.

Connection

[image]

Error

[image]